# Why this pot is split?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, rules, poker-theory

[image: ?]
Beside the flush, the bigger pair doesn`t count here ?

Answer (score 3):

Repeat after me: poker hands have five cards. EXACTLY five cards. No more, no fewer. In Hold'em, each player plays the best 5-card hand he can out of the seven available.

Vlad's best 5-card hand is A-8-7-4-2 of clubs.
His opponent's best 5-card hand is A-8-7-4-2 of clubs.

Split pot.

If, perchance, our hero had, say, the 6 of clubs in his hand, then his best five-card hand would have been A-8-7-6-4 of clubs, for the win. But such is not the case.

No one can play a flush here without playing exactly the board.

Comment: Each player plays 2 cards actually but the minimum combination is always 5. You shouldn't say "poker hands have five cards" sounds like something else than holdem. Omaha have 4 cards. combination is still 5 cards also.

Comment: Repeat after me: poker hands have exactly five cards. Period. No more, no fewer. Stop trying to complicate what is really quite simple. Cards are dealt in various ways to players and to the board, but then each player plays a *hand of five cards* to determine the winner.  Holdem, Omaha, draw, stud, lowball, all have 5-card hands. (Badugi is a popular exception).

Answer (score 0):

The winner of a hand is defined by the best combination of 5 cards each user has. 
In this case the best combination each player has is a flush. The rest doesn't matter.

If you have a pair 2♠2♣ and the board would be 8♣8♠7♣7♠A♣ you would not have 3 pairs.

Because the best combination with 5 cards you can have in this case would still be the board 8♣8♠7♣7♠A♣.

Your example is the same both players have 7♣4♣2♣8♣A♣ as their best 5 card combination. So the rest of the combinations don't count anymore.